# Trying to upload file stored using HTML 5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, html5-filesystem

I'm piecing together tutorials from the web to be able to build a tool where users can upload images offline in an HTML5 app to filesystem storage along with some personal details and when they are online, they can "sync" which uploads the files and their details to the server.

I've managed to get a simple page up that stores images in file storage &  sizes them down but I am unable to figure out how to post them using XMLHttpRequest. I've managed to push just the file data and store it one by one by using php://input (taken from [Upload file from HTML5 Filesystem by XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943683/upload-file-from-html5-filesystem-by-xmlhttprequest)) but I need it to be uploaded as a form field that I can retrieve via $_FILES.

This function in particular:

```
function (fileName, successFct) {
    getFileSystem(function (fileSystem) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'upload.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {}, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                fd.append('file' + i, file);
                fd.append('name' + i, 'name' + i);
            });

        }, errorFct);

        xhr.send(fd);
        }
    );
};
```

Full code can be seen @ http://pastebin.com/W0x9q6YH

In upload.php if I do the following

```
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
```

It just shows two empty arrays.

Comment: I found this site very helpfull: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with a similar problem: one thing I noticed about your code, you do not set your `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data`.

I do not have a working sample yet, but I'm pretty sure to use FormData, you need that old `multipart/form-data` magic.

Comment: I ended up using the base64 of the file and posting that, could not find a solution.

Comment: @MichaelM - I actually got code working on newer Android OS (so binary data in `multipart/form`). BUT then the app went live, and the devices used in production was much older. Long story short - eventually I also had to revert to base64 encoded post (and I tried *everything*...believe me). The main problem being that the Blob API available (if available at all) on older OSes just can't do what needs to happen