# Read .webm file from filesystem:chrome-extension://EXTENSION ID/persistent/ and create JavaScript File from it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, google-chrome-extension, html5-filesystem

I'm writing an Chrome Extension for screen capturing, which records video to `.webm` file inside `filesystem:chrome-extension://EXTENSION ID/persistent/myfile.webm` and later I need to upload this file through my website, so I need to have recording as a `File` `JavaScript` object which can be uploaded.

I tried using this code to fetch a file (I found it somewhere else on SO):

```
function urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType) {
    return (fetch(url)
        .then(function (res) {
            return res.arrayBuffer();
        })
        .then(function (buf) {
            return new File([buf], filename, {
                type: mimeType
            });
        })
    );
}
```

I call it with this code:

```
urltoFile("filesystem:chrome-extension://EXTENSION ID/persistent/myfile.webm","myfile.webm","video/webm").then(function (file) {
    //Here I would do something with the file
}
```

but all I get is this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I'm wondering how can I achieve what I need?

Comment: Why do you not get `File` object using `requestFileSystem`?

Comment: That URL is a dummy shown in devtools, not a real URL so yeah, read it via FileSystem API. Or maybe you can use [requestData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/requestData) from the stream instead of saving it to the file.

Comment: Note, `fetch()` allows requests only to certain protocols

Comment: @wOxxOm I need to have it saved so users can upload the file at any time.
I will have to experiment with FileSystem API then

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm stuck with this, do you have a piece of code which would accept filename like I have in my example for input, and return javascript File object for it, ready to upload?

Comment: It's not a file name in your example. It's a dummy URL shown in devtools, I suppose. How do you produce that file? Please add the relevant code.

Comment: I managed to get fileEntry from FileSystem with that filename, but I don't know how to convert this fileEntry to .webm file ready for upload

Comment: I don't know as well, but googling reveals at least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943683/upload-file-from-html5-filesystem-by-xmlhttprequest) right away.